# backup my whole raspberry pi so i can restore without re-installing or reconfiguring

Tags: backup, restore

I thought i did it all right. I had an image and backups from my raspberry
When the Raspberry crashed I thought:
 "just plugin the copy sdcard in another raspberry and run"

But it wasn't that simple (far from that), because the new raspberry I bought was a different version. 
I had to re-install and configure many things from again.

My question is.
Is there a way you can make a backup, so you can restore it to a sd-card. without without configure/install ?

Comment: @goldilocks that's really a different question.

Comment: How?  You ask, *"Is there a way you can make a backup, so you can restore it to a sd-card. without without configure/install?"*  There are a number of answers to exactly that question.  If you mean, "I want a guaranteed way to back up any Pi SD card so I can use it on any model of Pi, including ones released in the future, with absolutely no hassles" then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your are using **Raspbian**. It depends on how old your installation is that you make the image from. Older installations are not able to run on Raspberry Pi 3B+. You didn't tell us what "*different version*" means for your new Raspberry Pi. I suppose it is a RPi 3B+, and your old installation is made on a RPi 3B (for example). A clone from the RPi 3B will not run on a RPi 3B+ in that case. You have to use a [newer version of Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). This will run on all versions of a Raspberry Pi. If you make an image of the Raspbian version from the new running Raspberry Pi, that should also run in your older model. Just put the SD Card from new RasPi into the older one to check this.

Comment: It was a Raspberry Pi 2, with Raspbian (stretch).  I bought an 3b+ .  Reading your answer, Is it right that the the fastest way to get up and running after a crash is make a new sd-card with the newest Raspbian, and copy /etc and /home to it?

Comment: Just plain copying all of etc and home from an older installation into a newer one is probably a very bad idea.

Comment: @Richard Please read the comment from *goldilocks* above. Take an image from the RPi 3B+, flash it to another SD Card and put it into the RPi 2. Before doing it just test if the installation from the RPi 3B+ runs on the RPi 2 by putting the SD Card from the RPi 3B+ into the RPi 2 and boot it. Look at the [Release Notes](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt) on release `2018-03-13`. All versions before will fail in a RPi 3B+.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using sd card copier??? It comes with pi itself. You do need a spare sd but it will clone the card so if you want a duplicate or backup you'll have it and you can just put the other card in a pi as and when.

Comment: I had a image of the sd card, made with a sd card copier.  But you can't put an image in another raspberry, unless it's the same version.

Comment: I've never had an issue doing it. Did you backup the image to a hard drive or clone the sd with sd card copier? I've lost count of how many sd cards I've cloned with it.